# Is Azure Container Registry multi-region?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-cloud-services, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

We use Azure Container Registry to pull a larger image (~6Gb) to launch a cluster of many instances.. and it takes unusually long to pull the image.

We were wondering if Azure Container Registry is a truly multi-region service, or at least has a front-end CDN that has per-region local caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-geo-replication

This will allow you to bring your images closer to your different regions where your clusters are created.